# Hosting better-docs documentation on a website that is not Github Pages?

Tags: jsdoc

I was wondering if anyone has found a good solution for publishing their jsdoc/better-docs documentation on a website that isn't Github Pages (for privacy concerns)? I've built an api to retrieve the html files from the documented project but it loses the better-docs templating when it's no longer within the same project. Any recommendations would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Github is pretty secure and you can also make everything private if needed.

I would recommend Github, if not you can always opt for any alternatives like:

- GitLab
- SourceForge
- BitBucket
- Launchpad

you can read here more: https://itsfoss.com/github-alternatives/